# Plus and Minus Algorithm not working (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I have two buttons labeled plus and minus side by side and a display box at the center. I have a fixed value box at the top (say 10). When a user clicks plus the display box becomes one while the fixed value reduced to 9 and if I click the minus button, the fixed value returns to 10 while the display value becomes 0... It continues like that until the fixed value is exhausted. The functionality should work for all my four inputs. Below is what have tried.

```js
var minusBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#minus");
var plusBtn = document.querySelectorAll("plus");
var displayvalue = document.querySelectorAll("displayvalue");
var number = 0;
var min = 0;
var fixed = 10;
plusBtn.onclick = function() {


    if (fixed > number) {
        number = number++;
        numberPlace.innerText = number; /// Display the value in place of the number
    }
    if (number == max) {

    } else {


    }


}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="Fixed_number">10</div>


    <form>
        <label for=""> One
        <div id="">
            <button id="plus">+</button>
            <span id="displayvalue">0</span>
            <button id="minus">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
    </form>




    <form>
        <label for=""> Two
        <div id="">
            <button id="plus">+</button>
            <span id="displayvalue">0</span>
            <button id="minus">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
    </form>


    <form>
        <label for=""> Three
        <div id="">
            <button id="plus">+</button>
            <span id="displayvalue">0</span>
            <button id="minus">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
    </form>




    <form>
        <label for=""> Four
        <div id="">
            <button id="plus">+</button>
            <span id="displayvalue">0</span>
            <button id="minus">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
    </form>





    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.js">
</body>
```

Comment: btw, `id` has to be unique.

Comment: Please can you explain further

Comment: `querySelectorAll("plus");` and `querySelectorAll("displayvalue");` without class or id identifiers.

Comment: this line `number = number++;` is very wrong, what it does is it assaigns number to number and then increments number by one, simply replace it with `number++`

Comment: How are PHP and CSS involved?

Comment: @OluwafemiAkinyemi, please see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: Currently, there is no action set for that minus button - are you sure you've shared the whole code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must do it like this than change JS to

```
var total = document.querySelector(".Fixed_number");
var minusBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#minus");
var plusBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#plus");

plusBtn.forEach(function(item){
    item.onclick = function(){
        if( parseInt(total.innerText) > 0 ){
            item.nextElementSibling.innerText = parseInt(item.nextElementSibling.innerText) + 1;
            total.innerText = parseInt(total.innerText) - 1;
        }
    };
});

minusBtn.forEach(function(item){
    item.onclick = function(){
        if( parseInt(item.previousElementSibling.innerText) > 0 ){
            item.previousElementSibling.innerText = parseInt(item.previousElementSibling.innerText) - 1;
            total.innerText = parseInt(total.innerText) + 1;
        }
    };
});
```

And you must put type="button" for all buttons or else it will submit the form and reload the page.

Comment: thank you very much. Your comment actually solved my problem but can you please break the code down as I'm just starting Javascript. @hwnd